# How to read and print the hex stream of UDP packets coming to an interface using C program?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have a device that sends UDP Packets continuously to my PC to port 6053.

I wrote a C program for UDP client to receive those packets.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAX_BUF 2048
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int sfd,x=1,port=1234;
        struct sockaddr_in serv;
        socklen_t len=sizeof(serv);
        char buf[MAX_BUF]="";

        if(argc!=3){
              printf("Usage: %s ipaddr port\n",argv[0]);
              return 1;
        }

        port=atoi(argv[2]);
        if(port<1 || port>65535){
            printf("Invalid port %d\nValid ports 1-65535\n",port);
            return 1;
        }

        sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        if(sfd<0){
            perror("Socket\n");
            return 1;
        }

       if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(serv.sin_addr)) == 0){
          printf("Invalid IP\nUse ipv4 address only\n");
          return 1;
       } 

       serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
       serv.sin_port=htons(port);

      if((setsockopt(sfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&x,sizeof(x)))<0){
            perror("setsockopt:\n");
            return 1;
      } 

       while(1){
           if(recvfrom(sfd,buf,MAX_BUF,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,&len)<=0){
                 perror("Recv:\n");
                 close(sfd);
                 return 1;
           }
  //        printf("%.2X\n",buf);
            printf("%s\n",buf);
            memset(buf,0,MAX_BUF);
       }
       return 0;
}
```

Now if I compile and run the code:

```
gcc -o udp file.c

./udp 192.168.20.105 6053
```

there is nothing being displayed.

If I run with `gdb` I observed that `recvfrom()` is blocked there.

I thought it was a firewall issue so I added 6053 to be opened, it didn't work.

I disabled firewall, it didn't work.

But there are packets coming to my interface, seen using `tcpdump`

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port 6053
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code misses to [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) to an address:port  to listen to **locally** to the receiver.

---

The `src_addr` parameter passed to `recv_from()` is used for a different purpose.

The "*`from`*" in "`recv_from`" is not referring to where to receive from (not local, nor remote, nor mixed) but to tell the receiver from where the data that was received was sent.

From the [Linux man-page to `recv_from()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html):

> If src_addr is not NULL, and the underlying protocol provides the
>          source address of the message, that source address is placed in the
>          buffer pointed to by src_addr.

Comment: What should I give for src_addr then? And how do I receive from a random port of server? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RamanaReddy The `src_addr` parameter will tell you the source address of the datagram(s) you receive. You should fill in the `len` before each call to `recvfrom`.

Comment: @RamanaReddy: Passing the `src_addr` argument to `recv_from()` is optional. This is clearly stated in the documentation I linked, please by so kind and RTFM. "*Random sender*": Once *bound to* ***a local*** address:port the socket would *receive from* ***any remote*** address:port.